# Toggle CSS style on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions

Scratching my head over this for a while now I will lose hair soon.

I have a site here: 
http://ve.jago-staging.com/ I am trying to figure out how I can alter the code below so that when I click on featured posts the transition occurs same way, instead of just the round click links.

I've seen examples where I click on the element itself and it change style but not externally controlled.

round click still need to work

Thanks for the help

```
(function($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('.feature-slider a').click(function(e) {
                $('.featured-posts section.featured-post').css({
                    opacity: 0,
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                });
                $(this.hash).css({
                    opacity: 1,
                    visibility: 'visible'
                });
                $('.feature-slider a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: And what's the 'round click' that still needs to work..?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/PJAc8/ I've simplified the code hopefully its more clearer now?

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('.feature-slider a').click(function(e) {
            $('.featured-posts section.featured-post').toggleClass('your-extra-css');
        });
    });
```

And add the css stuff in your css:

```
.your-extra-css {
visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: You should not add the class 'your-extra-css' to the document already. jQuery does that for you after you click the h1 ;)

When jQuery adds the class you tell with your css code what it should do. As long the class is not added the 'featured-post' class is hidden or not displayed.

I've edited the code for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/PJAc8/4/